# C# : propertyinfo always empty

Tags: c#, reflection

i have an issue with c# reflection.
The object I want to reflect is the following :

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
    }

    public decimal CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string AlexaAccessToken { get; set; }

    public string GoogleHomeAccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

The code I use to reflect is the following :

```
    Dictionary<string,string> GetReplacement(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    { 

        Dictionary<string, string> toRet = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
        propertyInfos = typeof(ApplicationUser).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);

        Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
            delegate (PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
                { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });


        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            toRet.Add(propertyInfo.Name,propertyInfo.GetValue(applicationUser).ToString());
        }

        return toRet;
    }
```

The problem is that the dictionary is always empty because propertyinfo is always empty.
What is the problem?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: empty propertyinfo? What exactly do you mean? Is `propertyInfo` null? Or `propertyInfos`(plural)? Or what do you mean by "empty"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. bind via `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`
2. check for null values: `propertyInfo.GetValue(applicationUser)?.ToString()` or `Convert.ToString(propertyInfo.GetValue(applicationUser))`

Comment: The second - although not whrong - does not seem like OPs problem. If `GetVlue` retuened `null`, OP would get NRE, not an emtpy dictionary.

Comment: @HimBromBeere indeed; that could just be my local test rig - but: clearly two of those properties *can* be `null`, and *will* be `null` by default - so it makes sense to guard against them